# Proof by induction involving inequalities and summation.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, induction

Show that

$$\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{j^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$$

$\forall n\geq 1$

Let us denote our proposition by $P_n$. Testing for $P_1$ this shows us that

$$\sum^1_{j=1}\frac{1}{1}\leq2-1$$

$\therefore{\text{true for $P_1$}}$

Now, assuming that it holds for some natural number $m$. $P_m$ is true, where $m$ has the same boundaries as $n$. I.e $m\geq1$. Now we want to show as $P_m$ is true $P_m\rightarrow P_{m+1}$
$$P_m:\sum^m_{j=1}\frac{1}{j^2}\leq2-\frac{1}{m}$$
$$P_{m+1}: \sum^{m+1}_{j=1}\frac{1}{j^2}\leq2-\frac{1}{m+1}$$

We can manipulate the series to prove that it holds for $P_{m+1}$ too.

rewriting the sum we get $$\sum^{m+1}_{j=1}\frac{1}{j^2}=\sum^{m}_{j=1}\frac{1}{j^2}+\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}$$

$$\leq2-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{(m+1)^2}$$
$$=2-\frac{(m+1)^2-m}{m(m+1)^2}$$
$$\leq2-\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{2m-1}{m(m+1)^2}$$

This is where I'm confused. I'm stuck with something that does not equals our hypothesis. Have I done something wrong? Cause how I see it, most of the tricks in induction is just being good at algebra.

Comment: Being good at algebra helps with induction, and keep the end goal in mind

Comment: Did you mean $2-\dfrac{(m+1)^2\color{red}-m}{m(m+1)^2}$?

Comment: yeah, i'll edit the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The proof can be based on the inequality

$$\frac1{(n+1)^2}<\frac1{n(n+1)}$$

where the RHS forms a well-known telescoping series.

Comment: Oh, I never knew about telescoping series until now! Thank you so much, i'll add this into my toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Just say

$2-\dfrac1m+\dfrac1{(m+1)^2}\le 2-\dfrac1m+\dfrac1{m(m+1)}=2-\dfrac1{m+1}$